# Get all integers/dates between 2 values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
col val1 val2
A   1    6
B   44   46
C   2    5
```

How could I get the following output:

```
col val
A   1
A   2
A   3
A   4
A   5
A   6
B   44
B   45
B   46
C   2
C   3
C   4
C   5
```

which is the combination of col and val between val1 and val2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#standardSql
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS col, 1 AS val1,  6 AS val2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS col, 44 AS val1, 46 AS val2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' AS col, 2 AS val1,  5 AS val2 
)
SELECT col, val
FROM YourTable, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(val1, val2)) AS val
ORDER BY col, val
```

Comment: [Documentation for `GENERATE_ARRAY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_array) (there is also a `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function).

Answer (score 0):

I used a static public table that holds numbers for join. You can generate one for yourself. Also I had to mimic your table but you can replace that with a simple call.

```
#standardSql
select col,n.i from (
select * from
(select 'A' as col,   1 as val1,    6 as val2) union all 
(select 'B' as col,   44 as val1,    46 as val2) union all
(select 'C' as col,   2 as val1,    5 as val2)) d
join `fh-bigquery.public_dump.numbers_255` n on n.i>=val1 and n.i<=val2
order by 1,2
```